# Display won't turn on after opening lid

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

Here's some system info

```
$ system_profiler | grep Processor  
    Apple: AUDynamicsProcessor:  
    Apple: AUVoiceProcessor:  
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7  
      Processor Speed: 2.9 GHz  
      Number of Processors: 1  
  processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x522ce0  
$ sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string  
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
```

Almost every time I open my lid after my laptop having been sleeping for at least a couple of hours, the screen is dead and nothing wakes it up. My only option is to press the power button and perform a hard restart (which is probably not good). Now I have tried almost every suggested solution including resetting VRAM, PRAM and even performing a full format on my mac. I literally deleted everything on my SSD including reinstalling my OS and the problem still persists.

This is the error reporting page that comes up after I perform the hard restart, hope this helps.

```
Anonymous UUID:       7AB0D13A-1C6B-AE99-2EB5-75C01677F02A  


Fri Feb  5 11:54:15 2016  


*** Panic Report ***  
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800167f068): "Hibernate restore error e00002eb"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:2320  
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address  
0xffffff910ad9bb10 : 0xffffff80010df792   
0xffffff910ad9bb90 : 0xffffff800167f068   
0xffffff910ad9bc60 : 0xffffff80011df1fa   
0xffffff910ad9bcd0 : 0xffffff7f82a4b52d   
0xffffff910ad9bd10 : 0xffffff7f82a4ed79   
0xffffff910ad9bd30 : 0xffffff80016d38ff   
0xffffff910ad9bd90 : 0xffffff80016fe9e6   
0xffffff910ad9be00 : 0xffffff80016a48f9   
0xffffff910ad9be60 : 0xffffff800169c884   
0xffffff910ad9bec0 : 0xffffff80016a9b42   
0xffffff910ad9bf00 : 0xffffff80016a9c92   
0xffffff910ad9bf40 : 0xffffff80016b4d61   
0xffffff910ad9bf80 : 0xffffff80016b4f5c   
0xffffff910ad9bfb0 : 0xffffff80011ccf77   
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:  
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(4.0)[3BE4E926-E063-3BBD-BE05-F6F97358C7A4]@0xffffff7f82a40000->0xffffff7f82a9ffff  
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f81f7d000  
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F398CE94-0FBD-3E8E-A7AB-55F7F05A81ED]@0xffffff7f8192c000  


BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task  


Mac OS version:  
15D21  


Kernel version:  
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64  
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C  
Kernel slide:     0x0000000000e00000  
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001000000  
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000f00000  
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)  


System uptime in nanoseconds: 86811334880  
last loaded kext at 15856801657: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f83a88000, size 28672)  
loaded kexts:  
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70  
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1  
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.20.22  
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.6.0d0  
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0  
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 272.51.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics 10.1.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 272.51.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 272.51.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1  
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 800.20.24  
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 10.1.12  
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1  
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 208  
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 1020.17.1a1  
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.12.6  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver 4.1.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.13  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2  
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.4d1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 245.4  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 245.4  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4  
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 327.5  
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck 517.20.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1  
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1  
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0  
com.apple.BootCache 38  
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 3.7.7  
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.8.5  
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC 1.7.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.5.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.1.8  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 4.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 4.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0  
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 163  
com.apple.security.quarantine 3  
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 218.0.0  
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11  
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder 1  
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 108.0.1  
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3  
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 525  
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3  
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3  
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 204.3  
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0  
com.apple.kec.Libm 1  
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.6  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1  
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1110.26  
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8  
com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4  
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0  
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.12.6  
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0  
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7  
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 4.1.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 4.1.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.14d1  
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 205.1  
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.12.6  
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9  
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage 517.20.1  
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2  
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 3.7.7  
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.8  
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.8  
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 4.1.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 4.1.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 4.0.4  
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.6.2  
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.7  
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.5.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.8.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1  
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0  
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1  
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2  
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5  
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0  
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2  
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31  
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 4.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9  
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4  
com.apple.kec.pthread 1  
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2012), OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)

Comment: P.S. I tried running "cd /private/var/vm; sudo rm -f sleepimage" but the issue still persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MacBook (Late 2008 Unibody) does the same thing; once it's in the "deep deep sleep" state, it often fails to recognise that the lid has opened.

I've found that connecting and reconnecting the power adaptor with the lid open, then shut, then open again will make it "realise" that the the lid is open.

At this point, the keyboard becomes responsive (the caps lock LED will toggle if the key is pressed) and shortly afterwards the screen will light up.

A rather long-winded description of the sequence is:

1. Ensure power adaptor is connected and MagSafe LED is illuminated.
2. Open lid.
3. Disconnect power adaptor.
4. Reconnect power adaptor; wait for MagSafe LED to light and settle on a colour.
5. Close lid.
6. Repeat steps 3 and 4.
7. Repeat steps 2 through 4.

My theory is that the Mac's System Management Controller (SMC) gets in a state where it's unaware that the lid has opened, and toggling the power adaptor in each state (lid open, lid closed) prompts it to re-check the lid status.

N.b This method *doesn't* work if the Mac is genuinely switched off, rather than sleeping - for example, if its battery completely discharged before it could hibernate.